# hide modal tab bar controller - from within a view controller IN the tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a first view which has a funky menu thing. Then when you select a menu item it does `[self presentModalViewController:tbc animated:YES];` (tbc being a tab bar controller with 5 navigation controllers within it).

In each of the navigation controllers I have a Home icon in the navigation bar.

I want to be able to link this button up to do the opposite of `presentModalViewController:animated:` and show the funky original menu system.

Is there any way to do this at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you the following code

-(void)homeButtonClicked
{
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [funkyTabbarController setSelectedIndex:0];

}

Plese try it.